# SWT Widgets problems with binding

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

i am working on Eclipse RCP application, i need to create one bigger dialog, where i need to work with data binding. With TextFields works binding well. I have problem with 2 SWT widgets - Combo, Spinner.
In Spinner there will be numbers, where i can write too. Spinner use only values from Array of Strings.

For binding i use following code:

```
private void doBinding(MyPartComposite comp) {
    /* code for spinner */
    IObservableValue model = PojoProperties.value(MyPart.class, "age").observe(comp.result); //$NON-NLS-1$
    ISWTObservableValue target = WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify).observe(comp.ageSpinner);
    UpdateValueStrategy targetToModel = new UpdateValueStrategy(UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_CONVERT);
    this.dataBindingContext.bindValue(target, model, targetToModel, null);

    /* code for combo */
    model = PojoProperties.value(MyPart.class, "gender").observe(comp.result); //$NON-NLS-1$
    target = WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify).observe(comp.genderCombo);
    targetToModel = new UpdateValueStrategy(UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_CONVERT);
    this.dataBindingContext.bindValue(target, model, targetToModel, null);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Spinner` does not have text property, instead bind it to its selection. This sample below is working for me, I assume age property is integer and gender is String.

```
IObservableValue observeSelectionAgeSpinnerObserveWidget = WidgetProperties.selection().observe(ageSpinner);
IObservableValue ageResultObserveValue = PojoProperties.value("age").observe(comp.result);
dataBindingContext.bindValue(observeSelectionAgeSpinnerObserveWidget, ageResultObserveValue, null, null);
//
IObservableValue observeSingleSelectionGenderCombo = ViewerProperties.singleSelection().observe(genderCombo);
IObservableValue genderResultObserveValue = PojoProperties.value("gender").observe(comp.result);
dataBindingContext.bindValue(observeSingleSelectionGenderCombo, genderResultObserveValue, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see code for my spinner and combo, in spinner should be possibility to write text manually. Combo has not this possibility. Thanks for help.

```
    Spinner ageSpinner = new Spinner(myGroup, SWT.BORDER);
    ageSpinner.setMinimum(1);
    ageSpinner.setMaximum(100);
    GriData gd = new GridData();
    gd.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    ageSpinner.setLayoutData(gd);

    ComboViewer genderCombo = new ComboViewer(myGroup, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    gd = new GridData();
    gd.horizontalSpan = 2;
    gd.horizontalIndent = 10;
    gd.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    gd.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    genderCombo.getControl().setLayoutData(gd);
    genderCombo.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    genderCombo.setInput(this.genders.toArray(new String[0]));
```

Comment: You should move this content to your question as it is not an answer for it.